# Responsive image inside a gallery not keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to responsive imagery designs and I currently have an issue with some images not being responsive in my gallery. On window resize they don't keep the aspect ratio and become all squashed once i have my gallery full width in mobile view. Could anyone help me this please it would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.an-image {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.an-image:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  
  .image-gallery {
    margin: 100px 0;
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .image-gallery .content {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: center;
    background: none;
  }
  .image-gallery .container-content {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%; /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid red; /* just so you can see what's happening */
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .an-image:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .an-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%; /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

  }

  .an-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="images" class="image-gallery container">
  <div class="container-content">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="images/MillyCar.jpg" alt="Avatar" />
        <!-- add image one here with 150 word maximum caption -->
        <div class="image-caption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="images/MillyCar.jpg" alt="Avatar" />
        <!-- add image two here with 150 word maximum caption -->
        <div class="image-caption"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="images/MillyCar.jpg" alt="Avatar" />
        <!-- add image three here with 150 word maximum caption -->
        <div class="image-caption"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: remove the `height` and let it adjust automatically or use percentage `height:50%` or `height:50vh`

Comment: Remove the height on what part? Thanks for thr reply

Comment: all the `height: 250px;`

Comment: I still cant get this to work correctly :(

Comment: you have both height and width on image element set to 100% one has to be set to auto.